# Mixing memory sizes

Tags: imac, upgrade, memory

I'm looking at upgrading the memory in my mid-2011 iMac. Is there any problem with sticking in 2 4GB modules alongside the existing 2GB modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problem doing this. According to [this Apple kbase article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3011), you can install any compatible 2 GB or 4 GB RAM modules in each slot.

Only in [certain Mac Pros](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4433) do you have to worry about specific memory ordering.

> The iMac (Late 2009), iMac (Mid 2010) and iMac (Mid 2011) have four
>   SDRAM slots, each of which can accept a 2 GB or 4 GB SO-DIMM.

Comment: I've installed the memory, and there was no problem