# Does my 21.5 inch Late 209 iMac support mixing and matching memory modules?

Tags: imac, memory

I have looked at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42530/mixing-memory-sizes), and apparently my iMac does support mixing memory sizes. However, when I installed 2 4GB memory modules and 2 2GB memory modules, when I clicked  → About This Mac → More Info... → Memory, it said that I had only installed 4 2GB modules. I have checked the packaging, and it still verifies that they are both 4GB modules. For further information, I am running Version 10.9.1 Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use only the 4GB modules, what does it say then?
If it still see's them as 2GB each, it might be the RAM - who knows, maybe they just put the wrong sticker on it ;)